# What are the different ways of writing an IIFE? What are their use cases?

Tags: javascript, function, iife

I have started reading [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449370756) book. Chapter 2 says that there are different ways to write an IIFE:

```
!function (){}() 
~function (){}() 
+function (){}() 
-function (){}()
new function (){} 
1,function (){}() 
1&&function (){}() 
var i=function (){}()
```

The author says:

> Each manifestation has its own unique qualities and advantages—some
>   with fewer bytes, some safer for concatenation, each valid and each
>   executable.

I'm a newbie to JS. I know what an IIFE is, but what do these IIFE forms do exactly?

Comment: They missed my favourite, `(function() {})()`

Comment: virtually the same thing @JamesThorpe and it's twin without the dogs bollock, `(function() {}())`

Comment: These functions do absolutely nothing:-), see this blog for more information: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: And `void function() {}()`

Comment: @joews: Oh, wow, I've never seen it used, but you're 100% right of course.

Comment: @joews: `void` in js?

Comment: @batman `void <expression>`: "evaluate _<expression>_ and return `undefined`" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Why do this?

Before we get to the list, let's start with "Why do this at all?"

The answer is: To keep any variables and function declarations within the function private. Commonly this is to avoid globals (avoiding globals is a Good Idea<sup>TM</sup>). E.g.:

```
+function() {
    function foo() {
        /* ... */
    }

    foo();

    var answer = 42;
}();
```

Thanks to the IIFE (called a *scoping function* in this context), `foo` and `answer` are not globals. They're private to the code within the function, unless they get exported somehow.

You might do this even if not at global scope, just to avoid polluting whatever scope you're in.

IIFEs in general have other uses, but the style you've quoted is typically used for scoping.

#### The examples

The author is **dramatically** overstating the case that "each has its own unique qualities and advantages".

Unless you're *using* the return value, these are all exactly the same:

```
!function (){}() 
~function (){}() 
+function (){}() 
-function (){}()
1,function (){}() 
1&&function (){}()
```

The code within them is run, scoped within the function.

We can add these to that list as well:

```
(function(){}())
(function(){})()
0||function (){}() 
1^function(){}() // any binary math operator in place of ^ also works
```

Of course, the `1` in all of the above is not special. Could be any number (or just about anything else) for most of them, but the one using `&&` wouldn't work with `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, or `false` (the function wouldn't get run). Similarly, the one with `0||...` works as long as the value starting it is falsey.

In this one:

```
var i=function (){}()
```

...the only difference is that it declares a variable, `i`, which stores the return value. That can, of course, be a big difference. Consider this more obvious version of it:

```
var MyPseudoNamespace = function() {
    // ...

    return { /* nifty "namespace" stuff here */ };
})();
```

Finally:

```
new function (){}
```

That creates a new object and then calls the function with `this` set to the new object. If you don't use `this` within the function, it's utterly pointless. If you do, well, whether it's useful depends on what you do with `this`.

---

Note: If there's any possibility of code you don't control coming immediately before your scoping function (when you're combining and minifying files, for instance), it's best to start **all** of these off with a `;`, e.g.:

```
;!function (){}() 
;~function (){}() 
;+function (){}() 
;-function (){}()
;1,function (){}() 
;1&&function (){}() 
;(function(){}())
;(function(){})()
;0||function (){}() 
;1^function(){}() // any binary math operator in place of ^ also works
```

Several of them don't technically **need** one, but most of them do. The side-effects of not having them can be subtle, or catastrophic. Consider:

Code before your code:

```
obj.prop = function() {
    // Do something big and awful
}
```

Then your code:

```
(function(){}())
```

Automatic Semicolon Insertion will not kick in! The result? the `obj.prop` function gets **called**, with our IIFE passed into it as an argument. This will make it more obvious:

```
obj.prop = function() {
    // Do something big and awful
}(function(){}())
```

See how those `()` are now invoking the function?

Similarly:

```
obj.criticalValue = 42
```

then

```
+function(){}()
```

Suddenly, `criticalValue` is messed up. Why? Because:

```
obj.criticalValue = 42+function(){}()
```

Doh!

Having multiple `;` in a row is harmless, so if you start off with one, you're less likely to run into trouble.

Comment: The `(function() {})` form can lead to unexpected invocation if preceded by a non-II function expression with no semicolon: `var f = function(x) { console.log ("called with x: " + x) } /* new line, no semi-colon */
(function() { console.log("second") }())`

Comment: Sounds like a bizarre edge case but I've seen it happen in the wild. Moral: always use semicolons if you favour parethesis-style IIFEs (or just "always use semicolons").

Comment: @joews: Many of these can lead to unexpected outcomes with improperly terminated code in front of them, not just the `(function...)` ones. A leading semicolon is a good defense, that's what I always do with minifying, for example.

Comment: @joews: Thanks to your excellent note, I've added an entire thing about that to the end.

Comment: Ah, of course! I hadn't given the operator prefixes much thought before now.

Answer (score 0):

It is an optimization to concatenate multiple files into one. The idea there is, if the last line of the previous file does not end with a newline, then the first line in this file starts in the middle of a line.

Adding things like `;` before the function permits it to still work correctly.