# What is the right way of writing an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've seen two ways of writing an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression:

```
// A - Parentheses around 
// the function. Then 
// invocation.
var a = (function() {
  return 4 + 5;
})();

// B - Parentheses  
// around the function  
// AND the invocation.
var b = (function() {
  return 4 + 5;
}());

console.log('a: %s - b: %s', a, b);
// Result: a: 9 - b: 9
```

From what I can say: Both ways work.

But I'm wondering:

What is the correct way?

Or are there different situations where I have to prefer the one way over the other?

Comment: Both. And it your case you even don't need parenthesises. `var a = function(){...}();` would work too, but will look weird

Comment: As far as I remember Crockford recommends using the second approach, although I personally prefer the first one

Comment: And, another duplicate: [What is the difference between those self-executing anonymous function (aka IIFE) implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026909/what-is-the-difference-between-those-self-executing-anonymous-function-aka-iife)

Comment: And, another duplicate: [What are the different ways of writing an IIFE? What are their use cases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651198/what-are-the-different-ways-of-writing-an-iife-what-are-their-use-cases/33651269#33651269)

Comment: @Alexey Ten  - Great! Wasn't aware that is possible to call a function that way. Thanks a lot.