# Porting Javascript to Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to port a load of JS code I have inherited into Typescript. I have a file which is creating a module - `Bluetooth` - so goes through a whole load of functions adding them to the Bluetooth module, like this:

```
Bluetooth.xzy = function() {
...}

//repeated various times

module.exports = Bluetooth;
```

However, just in the file, there is a structure like this, it is mostly extending other classes. What is going on, I haven't seen this ()(); structure before. I am turning Bluetooth into a class, wuld the contents of this function be in a constructor?

```
(function () {
// Whole load of normal function logic
})();
```

Comment: Why don't you convert it into a method?

Comment: @C.Champagne Is there an advantage to doing that? This is a library, with a whole load of functions being exported as a module. As a class, I can import and extend the base class that this module is based on an cleanly export the whole bundle.

Comment: Your question, and specifically your title, aren't really describing what you are having a problem with.  You don't appear to be having an issue with porting code, as much as you have a question with the syntax of an existing code snippet.  In this case, the code snippet is an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651198/what-are-the-different-ways-of-writing-an-iife-what-are-their-use-cases

Comment: @Claies Awesome, thanks you! That's what I was after, but I didn't know what they were called. So would putting all that logic into the class constructor be a valid port?

Comment: probably yes, but IIFE is typically used to create a lexical scope for the variables within the IIFE.  Since one of the main goals of Typescript is to better manage variables and scopes, this is probably a case where evaluating the functions to determine *why* they were put into an IIFE in the first place will help to determine where they belong in the ported code.  It may be possible that the IIFE isn't really necessary, depending on what the code is and how sensitive the variables are, and that's not something that can be evaluated without seeing the code.